# Let X be a Hausdorff space and Y be a subset of X. Then, Y with the subspace topology is a Hausdorff space.

Tags: general-topology

[image]

Question: Let X be a Hausdorff space and Y be a subset of X. Then, Y with the subspace topology is a Hausdorff space.

This is what I did, can someone verify this and let me know if I am correct or wrong? Also, kindly let me know if my proof need some changes or modifications due to bad notations.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks correct.  The one pedagogical point I would make is to note explicitly that $U$ and $V$ are open in $X$.  That's clear, but perhaps not immediately obvious since you're working in two different topologies.

Comment: It's all correct.

Answer (score 3):

Everything that needs to be there is there, so it's a valid proof.  My only comments are about the style.

- The line where you recall the definition of the subspace topology on $Y$ is out of place.  You've already used this definition once; either you should state it at the top before you use it the first time, or leave it out altogether.
- “Hence a set containing $x$ in $Y$ is $U' = U \cap Y$, which is open in $Y$” might read better if it were written as “Hence $U' = U \cap Y$ is open in $Y$ and contains $x$.”  You're defining $U'$ in this sentence, so I feel like that definition should come first, and its properties later.

Otherwise good job!

Comment: Thanks a lot, will take a note of your suggestions and use it to make even better proof. Appreciate your help!!